# SAP or Dynamics AX integration with Xamarin Apps

Tags: mobile, sap, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

We are building enterprise apps to full fill customer needs by integrating SAP/Dynamics/SalesForce APIs for field service/purchase order use cases?

Does anybody know the SDK or Connectors to integrate SAP CRM or Dynamics AX APIs with Xamarin Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding AX 2012 mobile apps scenarios, you can leverage the connector for mobile application which uses Azure service bus.

More informations [here](https://mbs.microsoft.com/customersource/northamerica/AX/news-events/news/MSDYN_MobileAppsAX).